# Load an entire HTML project into VueJS component with Axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, xmlhttprequest, vue-component

I'm dealing with a 3D Vista tour web repository that I need to render in my Rails / Vue project.
[image: Files received from 3D vista web export]
Here are all the files exported from 3D vista. The only way to render the Virtual Tour is to upload those files on a server.

What I'm trying to do here is to render that project inside my Vue template. (This is a Rails /
VueJS App project)

Here is what I'have in my Vue file :

```
 <template>
    <div id="vr-frame" v-html="compiledHtml"> </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    name: 'vr',
    data() {
        return {
        fileName: "index.htm",
        input: ""
        };
    },
    computed: {
        compiledHtml() {
        return this.input;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        loadFile() {
        axios({
            method: "get",
            url: "../../assets/tours/v1/" + this.fileName
        })
            .then(result => {
            this.input = result.data;
            })
            .catch(error => {
            console.error("error getting file");
            });
        }
    },
}

</script>
```

I still don't know is that is actually possible and so far I don't it doesn't seem to work either.

What is the proper way to load and render an external web project into a VueJS template and is API appropriate for this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this using `v-html` because you are trying to load an entire html page rather than just some html content. Instead, try using an iframe using the [srcdoc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/srcdoc) attribute:

```js
<template>
  <iframe :srcdoc="compiledHtml" :src="fileName"></iframe>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    name: 'vr',
    data() {
      return {
        fileName: "index.htm",
        compiledHTML: ""
      };
    },
    methods: {
      loadFile() {
          axios({
            method: "get",
            url: "../../assets/tours/v1/" + this.fileName
          })
            .then(result => {
              this.compiledHTML = result.data;
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.error("error getting file");
            });
        }
    },
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Chase, I can see something rendered now. It's not finding the path to the file. How can I use a relative path without getting the route error from rails?

Comment: @RomainBOBOE If you're using webpack I'd try importing the file in your component and then using the imported value. You'll have to add a file-loader loader to your webpack build process to handle that though.

Comment: But using the `srcdoc` attribute you should be able to pass in a string. It only needs the `src` as a fallback attribute so you only need it if your users are using IE